# Turn a M1 MackBook Pro on automatically upon connecting AC power without opening the lid

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-silicon

I always use my M1 MacBook Pro connected to an external display with bluetooth mouse and Keyboard, so I don't need to open lid each time I want to startup.

I want the MacBook to automatically startup when I connect it to AC power? how can I do this?

Comment: Use a wired keyboard.

Comment: Sounds like you should have bought a Mini.

Comment: i just wanted to have option to go out and work any where if i'dlike